# Synchronous Youtube API calls inside loop

Tags: javascript, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, youtube-javascript-api

I'm trying to get all *"Liked Videos"* in Youtube via Youtube API, because I couldn't get it as a playlist. Since I'm limited with 50 *`maxResults`*, I'm looping around the videos 50 by 50. I'm printing the results, getting *`nextPageToken`* then making another API call on the next turn of loop.

My problem is *`nextPageToken`* is not changing so I keep getting the same set of 50 videos. I guess this cause by the asynchronous API calls, so the loop runs, registers all calls before getting the first(second in the scenario) answer. Thus, all registered calls registered with same *`nextPageToken`*, I'm getting same results. According to this scenario I tried to find a way to call lists without *then()*, I failed.

```
'use strict';
let maxResults = 50;
gapi.client.youtube.videos.list({
        'part': 'snippet,contentDetails,statistics',
        'myRating': 'like',
        'maxResults': maxResults
    }).then(function (response) {
        let likedVideosCount = response.result.pageInfo.totalResults;

        if (likedVideosCount > 0) {
            let videoIndex = 0;
            //let playlist = addPlaylistItem('Liked Videos', likedVideosCount);
            let pageVideoCount = response.result.items.length;
            if (likedVideosCount > maxResults) {
                let nextPageToken = response.result.nextPageToken;
                let _likedVideosCount = likedVideosCount - pageVideoCount;
                for (let page = _likedVideosCount; page > maxResults; page -= pageVideoCount) {
                    _likedVideosCount -= pageVideoCount;
                    gapi.client.youtube.videos.list({
                        'part': 'snippet,contentDetails,statistics',
                        'myRating': 'like',
                        'maxResults': maxResults,
                        'pageToken': nextPageToken
                    }).then(function (videoResponse) {
                       nextPageToken = videoResponse.result.nextPageToken;
                        console.log(nextPageToken );
                        }

                    });
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: There are many answered questions about synchronizing for-loop promises..

Comment: you'll need to chain the promises returned by `gapi.client.youtube.videos.list` - something like https://pastebin.com/L08RNZ04

Comment: Is this the true way to get all list? I mean page by page... So this torture is just for measuring call costs easier by Google?

Comment: well, your code attempts to get it page by page - what's the issue? you want to make multiple calls at once? youtube doesn't let you do that it seems - judging by the `nextPageToken` parameter - clearly youtube is limiting the requests to be sequential not parallel

Comment: I just want to get all items of list. But it seems Google prefers less data more calls.